# AngularJS PDF viewer not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

I am trying to display a PDF that has it's url based off of an agularjs variable.  I have it working for google chrome but it doesn't seem to work in IE.  I have tried hard coding the url into the page and it works perfectly.  Here is the plunker to show my results: http://plnkr.co/edit/gFfGQCzAfmf2zf5C2Bpc?p=preview

> Please note, the only way to see my issue is if you use plunker in IE not Chrome.  And my IE and Adobe are both up to date.

My theory is that Adobe is fireing up with the url as {{documentSrc}} and then angular runs and replaces that variable with the value, and then Adobe never recognizes it.  Is this true? and if so, how do I fix this?  If not, what is going on?

Code

```
<object data="{{documentSrc}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="700px"></object>
```

Comment: Have you tried `ng-attr-data` in the place of `data`?

Comment: That received an Access denied alert in IE.

Comment: Are these resources hosted from the same domain?

Comment: They are going through an api that is on the same server.  I am sure this isn't a pref-light issue with the browser.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using, and on which version of Windows?

Comment: @Sampson : I have updated the plunker to display multiple pdf viewer structures that work in chrome that don't work in IE.  I have also tried a number of angular pdf libraries such as http://sayan.ee/angularjs-pdf/.  Is there a specific reason why they all fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a directive for the object element. You will need create a watch to detect changes in your data and type bindings. There is an additional gotcha in that you will need to keep track of your directive element if you intend to change bindings multiple times.

See here: http://embed.plnkr.co/fFtkcG/preview

```html
 <object-reloadable>No document selected</object-reloadable>
```

```js
.directive('objectReloadable', function() {
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs) { 
    var currentElement = element;

    scope.$watch('documentSrc', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        scope.documentSrc = newValue;
        var html = '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + newValue + '"></object>';
        var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
        currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
        currentElement = replacementElement;
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
     scope: false,
    link: link
  };  
})
```